# Error when installing EntityFramework package over NuGet

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nuget

I tried to install EntityFramework 4.1 on VS 2010 through NuGet. I searched and found the package through "Tools > Library Package Manager > Add Library Package Reference" tool and I got this error: "This package (or one of its dependencies) contains powershell scripts and needs to be installed from the package manager console.". This is what I did to fix it:

Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console
PM > get-package -remote -filter entityframework
(got some results including EntityFramework 4.1.10311.0)
PM > install-package -id EntityFramework
Successfully added 'EntityFramework ...

The question is:
1. What was wrong with "Add Library Package Reference" option? In this MS tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part4-cs it seems that it should work fine.
2. Is there a better solution?

Thanks to all.

Comment: For more on Package Manager Console commands check http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Package%20Manager%20Console%20Command%20Reference

Comment: Thanks for posting how to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What version of NuGet are you using? Update to the latest in the VS Gallery. More info on how to upgrade here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetActionPlanUpgradeTo11SetupAutomaticUpdatesGetNuGetPackageExplorer.aspx

In 1.1 we allows packages with install.ps1/uninstall.ps1 to be installed from the dialog, this wasn't the case before.

Comment: +1. This fixed it for me. I had to removed NuGet1.0, and then install 1.1 from http://www.nuget.org/ rather than through VS for some reason. But with nuGet 1.1, EntityFramework installed via NuGet with no problems.

Comment: Yes, it works. Just Installed, without uninstall, and fixed. Tks.